# InfoPath - Populate text box from dropdown list

Tags: infopath, xml

I've been playing around with info path, watched countless YouTube videos but I cant seem to find a way to populate two text boxes that are linked to a drop down selection.

I would like the user to select an entry from a connected XML table and the two adjacent text fields automatically populate with the data from the same row in the XML table.

I've managed to list all account numbers in the dropdown field (if anyone knows how to make this field type searchable with an auto complete feature that would be a bonus).  I've then also managed to replicate this in the sales person and account name fields but rather then displaying the specific entry from the XML row it displays all entries in the XML table.

I'm aware this could be a bit of a noob question but if anyone knows how to fix or point me in the right direction that would be great.  I can send the file in case anyone has time to have a look (I've removed the values from the text boxes and also the rules that were not working).

EDIT - here's a dropbox link to my working files... https://www.dropbox.com/s/qy8bssrzuwfe08m/accountList.zip?dl=0

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you added your rule on the SalesPerson and AccountName fields. You should put the rule on your OBM field so that when it changes it updates the other text fields.

So in your OBM text box add a rule to set your SalesPerson field equal to the AccountList[SalesPerson] and filter that to where your AccountList[OBM] is equal to Infopath[OBM] field. Repeat for AccountName.

Let me know if you have trouble doing that.