# InfoPath - Can't populate text boxes from XML

Tags: infopath, xml

So the other day I asked how to populate dropdowns from from an XML file, that question was answered here
[InfoPath - Populate text box from dropdown list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/171538/infopath-populate-text-box-from-dropdown-list). Now I'm looking to improve on my forms functionality by uploading some form fields to an access data base, i've sucessfully completed that function however I'm now looking to replicate the rules in my previous post.

I've connected the XML data connection and included the fields at the top of my form, the three fields (OBM, Sales person & Account Name), all display the first entry on the XML file however I can't seem to implement the rule where once the OBM is changed (options are 1,2,3... to 10), the sales person and account name change respectively.

Am I trying to achieve something that cant be done on this form or am I missing something obvious?

I've uploaded the files to dropbox, If anyone can help I'd be really pleased.

Here's the files... https://www.dropbox.com/s/egb8f4447vvf2uj/accountList%20%282%29.zip?dl=0

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So let me understand the process here. Infopath form looks up OBM from XML and fills in the SalesPerson and AccountName for corresponding OBM from the XML file. And then you have a bunch of fields at the bottom that are manually filled out and get submitted to the access database?

Why do you have two of each for the OBM? Also your lookup fields at the top should be from the Main Fields, but you added OBM, Sales Person, AccountName from the data connection fields. That is why your lookup and rules are failing. You are trying to run a rule to set the xml file field which is not going to work.